# MAMP Pro 5.6 not available

Tags: mamp

Is anyone else having problems getting hold of MAMP 5.6?

A colleague of mine downloaded it a few days ago but it is no longer available on their site. The latest version they have is 5.5 yet the only reply I get from their tech support is to try this link which is for 5.7 https://downloads.mamp.info/MAMP-PRO/releases/5.7/MAMP_MAMP_PRO_5.7.pkg

Which itself gives me a 404 error.

Thanks

Gary

Answer (score 0):

At last I have a solution…

"This seems to be a caching problem with cloudflare. I´ve just deleted the cache. If the link still isn´t working, could you please try a different browser?"

All seems to be working now ;-)

Gary